# Automatic activity not performing

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Created a workflow with basic as below. [image: PFA the workflow attached]

Created a calss library, used ProgId, set comvisible true and registerd the assembly in the Tridion server.

**This is the way i have tested:**

1. Created a component
2. Finished the activity from the work list.
3. Navigated to the "Global Work list" and finished the Reviewer activity by myself by choosing the "Back to Author" step and clicked the "Finish" button.

**The item is not moved to the author. but when i finish the activity again from the global work list, the item moved to author.**

It seems that my code is not performing the activity because i tried removed the below VB script code and tried with the default automatic script code.

```
' Script for Automatic Activity Content Manager Workflow
FinishActivity "Automatic Activity Finished"
```

It behaves the same as above. so i decided my code is not worked. Can any one please help on this?

**Below is the VBScript I used in the script box of "Back to Author":**

```
Option Explicit

Dim workflowHandler
Set workflowHandler = CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler");

If Not workflowHandler Is Nothing Then
    Call workflowHandler.MoveBackToActivity(Cstr(CurrentWorkItem.ID, "Create or Edit     Component")
End If
Set workflowHandler = Nothing
```

**Below is the C# Code:**

```
public void MoveBackToActivity(string workitemid, string strActivitytoMove)
    {

        try
        {
            Session session = new Session();
            WorkItem workitem = new WorkItem(new TcmUri("workitemid"), session);
            ActivityInstance currentactivity = workitem.Activity as ActivityInstance;
            ProcessInstance procInstance = currentactivity.Process as ProcessInstance;

            IEnumerable<ActivityInstance> ieActivities = procInstance.Activities                    
            .Select (s => s)
            .Where (w => w.Title.IndexOf(strActivitytoMove) !=-1)
            .OrderByDescending(w =>w.StartDate);

            if (ieActivities != null && ieActivities.Count<ActivityInstance>() > 0)
            {
                ActivityInstance targetactivity = ieActivities.ElementAt(0);
                User lastperformuser = targetactivity.Performers.ElementAt(targetactivity.Performers.Count<User>() - 1);
                ActivityFinish finish = new ActivityFinish(targetactivity.FinishMessage, lastperformuser, workitem.Session);
                currentactivity.Finish(finish);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What state is the activity in at the point it hasn't moved back to the author as expected?

Comment: select the "Back to author" activity form the "Review" state.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. Look for the value in the State column of the Global Work List...

Comment: Ok, created component, finished the activity, assigned to reviewer (at that time status is : Assigned" in global work list) and i finished the activity from the global work list, again the status is Assigned. I chose back to author shold be the next activity

Comment: If you open the item from the Global Work List does it show that the current activity is "Back To Author"? Normally if an automatic activity is failing then you will see that the state is "suspended" and there'll be an error logged in the Event Viewer. If the state is assigned, and the activity is an automatic one then there's likely an issue with the workflow service.

Comment: When i open the particular item in Global work list, Activity shows as " back to author" Performer ""(empty), Assigned to "NT\AUTHORITY SYSTEM" Approval Status "Staging"

Comment: When it's in this state, what happens if you stop and start the workflow service?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13445/discussion-between-user1428019-and-jeremy-grand-scrutton)

Comment: I have restarted the workflow agent service, and opened the item from the global work list, now the Performer status is changed to "NT\AUTHORITY SYSTEM" but still the itme is not moved to author. if i again finish the activity manually, then the item is moved to author at the same time the performer of the above task also changed as me from "NT\AUTHORITY SYSTEM"

Comment: When the performer is the System user, what is the state of the activity?

Comment: Is there anything logged in the Event Viewer? An automatic activity should only show as assigned for extended periods of time if the workflow service isn't running.

Comment: How and where to check the event viewer?

Comment: Nothing is there in the event log

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that you are using an API that is NOT supported in Automatic Activities. The only processes where you are allowed to use TOM.NET are Event System handlers and Template Building Blocks as documented [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_19AF6C2427DF4781A866981FA8D62192).

Automatic Workflow Activities - if not developed with VBScript - must use the CoreService interface.

The good news is that I know for a fact this works - plenty of people got it to work in many implementations. The bad news (for you) is that the error is in your code. Have you tried debugging/step-by-step through your code yet? You can attach to to the workflow process (cm_wf_svc.exe) and figure out what's wrong with the code much faster than we can.

Here's a really simple snippet to finish an activity with CoreService:

```cs
ActivityFinishData activityFinish = new ActivityFinishData
    {
        Message = "Automatically Finished from Expiration Workflow Extension"
    };
ActivityInstanceData activityInstance = 
    (ActivityInstanceData)processInstance.Activities[0];
client.FinishActivity(activityInstance.Id, activityFinish, readOptions);
```

BTW - If you intended to use TOM.NET anyway, why did you bother [asking which API to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185079/which-api-can-i-use-for-writing-sdl-tridion-workflow-activities)?

Comment: Hi Nuno, Thanks for your comment, I had a step by step guide which is SDL, in that document they have used the above C# and VB Code, thats the reason am getting confused whether to got with TOM.NET or Core Service. BTW, i never debugged the workflow. can i attach the cm_wf_svc.exe from the client machine visual studio?

Comment: I'm afraid that the person from SDL that provided you that sample and guide was incorrect/unaware of this limitation. I suggest you let him/her know of that. Yes you can attach to the service from a client machine as long as your server allows you do do that. Refer to MSDN for help on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Following the Nuno's answer, yes you should change the code to use TOM or Core Services. TOM .Net is not supported because it is using a different thread apartment than the underlying technology we use for workflow (COM).

About the issue I have checked that you are calling the activity like this.

```
Call workflowHandler.MoveBackToActivity(Cstr(CurrentWorkItem.ID, "Create or Edit     Component")
```

It looks like the activity name is not matching. there are some strange characters between "Edit" and "Component"

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic activities are executed by the Workflow agent service. An Assigned state may indicate that it's just not being picked up by the service. Is your service running correctly, and are things like queue notifications set up properly?

Comment: I have restarted the workflow agent service, and opened the item from the global work list, now the Performer status is changed to "NT\AUTHORITY SYSTEM" but still the itme is not moved to author. if i again finish the activity manually, then the item is moved to author at the same time the performer of the above task also changed as me from "NT\AUTHORITY SYSTEM"

Comment: OK - well it sounds like your agent wasn't running properly. Now it is picking up the activity, but now that I look at your code, you are writing TOM.NET code in an automatic activity script. This is not supported. You can write your code in C#, but then you must use COM/.NET interop. A PIA is provided for this purpose. Apart from that, your logic doesn't always result in the activity being finished.

Comment: You mean using interop dlls? with TOM API? can i use coreservice.client.dll using core service API? and I dont understant that "your logic doesn't always result in the activity being finished"

Comment: @DominicCronin, this is what he's doing ;)  It could well be down to the logic though - in this instance, if the finish isn't called then you'd expect that the activity would show as started, and remain that way until manually finished, rather than showing as assigned...

Comment: @user1428019 "I dont understant that "your logic doesn't always result in the activity being finished"" is simple really. You only call currentactivity.Finish from within an if statement. If the if doesn't resolve to true then you will never finish the activity and it will never progress through the workflow.